# La fecha sea formeteada con timeago.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, handlebars.js

Buenas estoy haciendo consultas a Mongodb el cual me trae datos en los que se incluye fechas pero al pintarlas con handlebars(plantilla html) no logro que se vea, he usado timeagojs para que de tiempo atras (just now, etc). 
Mediante la consola de vscode logro ver que efectivamente se formateo y ahora como la pinto?

```html
const {format} = require("timeagojs")  

ventasCtrl.cuentaUsuario = async function(req, res){
    await Orden.find({user: req.user}, function (error, ordens){
      if(error){
        return res.write("!Error")
      }
      var carro;
      var fechas;
      ordens.forEach(function (orden){
        carro = new Carro(orden.carro)
        orden.items = carro.generarArreglo(); 
        fechas = format(orden.fecha)       
      });      
      console.log(fechas)
      res.render("venta/ventas", {ordens})
    }).sort({ date: "desc" })    
  }
  
module.exports = ventasCtrl;
```

El console me muestra que efectivamente se formateo
[image: consola de vscode]

el HTML con handlebars lo tengo asi

```html
 {{#each ordens}}
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4><strong>{{fecha}}</strong></h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                                <th scope="col">Cant.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        
                        {{#each items}}              
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                   <img class="img-thumbnail" width="50" srcset="{{this.item.imagen}}">     
                                </th>
                                <th scope="row">{{this.item.titulo}}</th>
                                <th scope="row">{{this.cantidad}}</th>
                                <th scope="row" class="text-right">${{this.item.precio}}</th>
                                <th scope="row" class="text-right">${{this.precio}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        {{/each}} 

                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-right">TOTAL</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-right">${{this.carro.totalPrecio}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>                            
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{else }}
    <div class="card mx-auto">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Hola! {{user.name}}</h1>
            <p clsss="lead">No tienes pedidos</p> 
            <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
                <a href="/pedidos/add" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Agregar Productos</a>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
```

y la vista queda asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que en la function que se ve en la busqueta "orden" contiene la fecha y otros datos. Ademas "carro" contiene los productos, precios y totales

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar el dato de fecha formateada hacia la vista. Una opcion es agregarla como un nuevo atributo al objeto orden por ejemplo:

```
const {format} = require("timeagojs")  

ventasCtrl.cuentaUsuario = async function(req, res){
    await Orden.find({user: req.user}, function (error, ordens){
      if(error){
        return res.write("!Error")
      }
      var carro;
      ordens.forEach(function (orden){
        carro = new Carro(orden.carro)
        orden.items = carro.generarArreglo(); 
        orden.fecha_formateada = format(orden.fecha)       
      });      
      res.render("venta/ventas", {ordens})
    }).sort({ date: "desc" })    
  }

module.exports = ventasCtrl;
```

Luego en la vista

```
{{#each ordens}}
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4><strong>{{fecha}}</strong></h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                                <th scope="col">Cant.</th>
                                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        {{#each items}}              
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                   <img class="img-thumbnail" width="50" srcset="{{this.item.imagen}}">     
                                </th>
                                <th scope="row">{{this.item.titulo}}</th>
                                <th scope="row">{{this.cantidad}}</th>
                                <th scope="row" class="text-right">${{this.item.precio}}</th>
                                <th scope="row" class="text-right">${{this.precio}}</th>
                                <th scope="row" class="text-right">${{this.item.fecha_formateada}}</th>    
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        {{/each}} 

                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-right">TOTAL</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-right">${{this.carro.totalPrecio}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>                            
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{else }}
    <div class="card mx-auto">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Hola! {{user.name}}</h1>
            <p clsss="lead">No tienes pedidos</p> 
            <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
                <a href="/pedidos/add" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Agregar Productos</a>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..llevo dias buscando la solucion y todo era por la palabra "orden"...eres un genio

Comment: si la respuesta es correcta marcala de esa forma las demas personas que pasen por aqui pueden saber si el problema se resolvio o no. saludos